# Passing complex linking flags from Makefile to setup.py

Tags: c++, python, makefile, setuptools, setup.py

I am writing Python 2.7 C++ extension. The Python extension wraps part of C++ library (Kaldi).
Previously I created shared library and distributed it with the Python extension. (I needed set up LD_LIBRARY_PATH).

I want to compile the extension statically. The Kaldi library can be compiled statically (with `-fPIC` flag). The problem is that the compilation depends on other libraries and flags are generated by the `configure` script.

I want to compile the extension using `setup.py` and "steal" the compilation setup from `Makefile`.
How would you do it?

The command for linking the shared library was:

```
$(CXX) -shared -DPIC -o $@ -Wl,-soname=$@,--whole-archive $^ -Wl,--no-whole-archive $(EXTRA_LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

In the `setup.py` I had:

```
ext_modules.append(Extension('pykaldi.decoders',
                         language='c++',
                         include_dirs=['..', 'fst'],
                         library_dirs=['.'],
                         libraries=['pykaldi'],
                         sources=['pykaldi/decoders.pyx'],
                         ))
```

The `$(EXTRA_LDLIBS)`,`$(LDFLAGS)` and `$(LDLIBS)` are generated by `configure` script.
The `$(LDLIBS)` contains some static libraries some shared.

NOW I have

```
if STATIC:
    # STATIC 
    # TODO extract linking parameters from Makefile
    library_dirs, libraries = [], []
    extra_objects = ['pykaldi.a', ]
else:
    # DYNAMIC
    library_dirs = ['.'],
    libraries = ['pykaldi']
    extra_objects = []
ext_modules.append(Extension('pykaldi.decoders',
                             language='c++',
                             include_dirs=['..', 'fst'],
                             library_dirs=library_dirs,
                             libraries=libraries,
                             extra_objects=extra_objects,
                             sources=['pykaldi/decoders.pyx'],
                             ))
```

Note 1: I am using Cython, but it should not matter.

Note 2: I know I can compile the extension using `make`, I would prefer `setup.py` for better deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to link a static extension to python when you build the **python** executable.

That is because extensions are loaded into the interpreter using dlopen (or LoadLibrary on Windows) and this functionality can not support static 'libraries' which are nothing more than a tarball of the object files.  Object files are a raw form still unusable by the system runtime until they've gone through a linking phase.